# Is Prabhu Jagatbandhu considered a reincarnation of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu?

Tags: avatars, vaishnavism, chaitanya

Prabhu Jagatbandhu was a nineteenth century Vaishnava saint in Bengal. He was the founder of the Mahanam Vaishnava Sampradaya. Now, according to Wikipedia, he is considered a reincarnation of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu:

> Considered by his followers to be a **re-incarnation of Chaitanya**, he spent much of his life meditating and preaching in the Sri Angan ashram in Faridpur, British India (present day Bangladesh).

Is Wikipedia correct in saying Jagatbandhu is considered as an incarnation of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu. I haven't heard much about him from ISKCON or any Vaishnava.

Comment: That would only mean that krishna chaitanya did not attain mukti as he reincarnated ...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi If you use that argument, that would mean Rama didn't get multi too.

Comment: only god incarnates as saints or avatara. If saint again reincarnates then how its mukti ?

Comment: Saints can be avataras @RakeshJoshi

Comment: avatara means of god. Saint reincarnation is not avatar

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Saints cannot be incarnation of God?

Comment: they can be but then you are saying X saint was.incarnation of Y god and then X again had an incarnation. Incarnation will.be of god only na ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Well, I get your point but many say like that. Idk why.

Comment: that is why such questions will arise

Comment: Do you have any reference where mahaprabhu promised future incarnations?

Comment: @RaRe Actually yes, I wrote an answer on this a few months back: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24913/where-is-the-next-incarnation-of-caitanya-mahaprabhu-supposed-to-be-born-and-wh/24915#24915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Prabhu Jagatbandhu is considered an incarnation of Krishna and Chaitanya Mahaprabhu by members of the Mahanam sect founded by him.  Here is what [this Mahanam sect website](http://web.archive.org/web/20170618214027/http://www.mahanam.org:80/guruparampara.html) says:

> Sri Sri Prabhu Jagatbandhu Sundar, the resident worshipped deity of the Mahanam Sampraday, is a condensed living idol of self-restraint, harinam and austere –practices. Like Sri Gour Hari, Prabhu was tall, bright complexioned, having all the divine traits and always clad in white robes. For the benefit of ignorant, He revealed his own identity by saying “The supreme Godhead and eternally original Sri Govinda is Sri Sri Krishna and Sri Sri Gouranga. One who is the total unification and energy of these two Lilas is Sri Sri Haripurush Jagatbandhu. That is only me - do you understand? -- the Lila combination of all things.”  Prabhu Jagatbandhusundar was not a Guru in ordinary sense, he was Jagadguru, the Sureme Godhead incarnate, Lord Sri Krishna Himself.

Also, they think he's the fulfillment of a prophecy given in the Chaitanya Bhagavatam.  [Here](https://ia801901.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/29/items/LiliaLifeOfPrabhuJagatbandhuSunder/prabhu_JagatBandhu_book_KLD_jp2.zip&file=prabhu_JagatBandhu_book_KLD_jp2/prabhu_JagatBandhu_book_KLD_0072.jp2&scale=6.193245778611632&rotate=0) is what K.L. Datta says in his biography of Prabhu Jagatbandhu:

> In the Chaitanya-Bhagavat we find that Gour promised his devotees that he has two more manifestations of this kind "Kritan" (celestial joy) will be evident.

But I don't know of any Vaishnavas outside of the Mahanam sect that consider him an incarnation.